# Updating column with it's current value

Tags: sql-server, optimization

I have a stored proc that should conditionally update a bunch of fields in the same table. Conditionally, because for each field I also pass a "dirty" flag and a field should be updated only if flag is set to 1.

So I'm  going to do the following:

```
create proc update 
@field1 nvarchar(1000), @field1Dirty bit, ...other fields...
as 
begin
    update mytable
    set field1 = case when @field1dirty = 1 then @field1 else field1 end,
    ... same for other fields
end 
go
```

Question - is SQL Server (2008) smart enough to not physically update a field if it's been assigned its own value, like in case if @field1dirty = 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Question - is SQL Server (2008) smart enough to not physically update
> ```
>
> a field if it's been assigned its own
>   value, like in case if @field1dirty =
>   0?

No you should add a where clause that says...`where field <> the value you are updating to`.

This doesn't seem like a big deal at first, but in truth it can create a massive amount of overhead.  One example, think about triggers.  If that updates every field in the table, that trigger will fire for every row. YIKES, that's a lot of code execution that's needless, especially if that code is say, moving updates rows to a logging table.  I'm sure you get the idea.

Remember, you're updating the field, it just happens to be the same value it was before. It's actually good that this happens, because that means that you can still count the field as modified (think timestamp etc.). If it didn't think updating the field to the same value was modifying the row, you wouldn't know if someone inadvertently (or deliberately) tried to change data.

Update due to comments:
Link to the [coalesce function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Example: 
For handling null parameter values in your stored procedure

```
Update Table SET My_Field = COALESCE(@Variable, My_Field)
```

This doesn't get around what I was talking about before with the field being updated to the same value, but it does allow you to check parameter and conditionally update the field.

Comment: Good point, but I sure hope people aren't putting in triggers everywhere!

Comment: Me too, but it was the easiest example I could come up with on the fly that got the point across.

Comment: Can't add where clause because in reality there are several fields in one update - as I said the case shown was the simplest.

Comment: I guess i'll have to go with dynamic sql then

Comment: @Andrey - you can still use the `WHERE` just have them separated by `OR`.  SQL Server writes a whole row at a time, so if ANY condition is met it will rewrite the whole row anyways and your performance won't suffer.

Comment: @JNK: fields that are not "dirty" will not have values (to avoid unnecessary network bandwidth between app server and db server), so I should only update "dirty fields"; thus OR'ing where clauses will not help

Comment: @Andrey you want to use the Coalese function in that case.

Comment: @Andrey - Use the `CASE` and the `WHERE` clause...If you aren't specifying a field as dirty it will be reassigned its own value.  If you are ALWAYS updating at least one field, then the point is moot since you are updating (and therefore rewriting) every row anyways.

Answer (score 2):

SQL doesn't check the value before writing to it.  It will overwrite it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server will perform the update.  The row will be updated as an entire row, so if one column in the row does have FieldxDirty = 1, the update is required anyway.  There's no optimization gained in the SET clause.

@Kevin's answer will help more than optimizing the SET clause.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to come here with an opinion, but I have nowhere else to write :-)
There should at least be a kind of "hint" possibility to tell the UPDATE statement to generally NOT update to the same value.

There are at least 2 reasons I can think of:
1st: the value to update to can be a complicated expression and it is a waste of execution time (not to mention the maintenance of expression changes) to express it again in the WHERE clause. Think also of NULL values!
Ex. UPDATE X SET A = B WHERE ISNULL(A,'') <> ISNULL(B,'')

2nd: we have a synchronized mirroring scenario where the "backup" server is physically placed in another part of the city. This means, that the write to disk is comitted first when the backup-server has performed the write. There is a huge time difference between the write and skip writing. When the developers created the application, they worked in a test environment without mirroring. Most of the UPDATE statements just did not change the values, but it did not matter in the test environment. After deloying the application to production with mirroring, we would really love to have that "only changed value" hint. Reading the original value and checking it does not take time compared to writing